Какой должен быть прокинут partition key для cosmos db?
Разбираюсь с nosql бд. И решил сделать простой репозиторий.
Наткнулся на проблему с созданием записи в контейнере. Ошибка с ключей partition.
[HttpPost("language")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLanguage(Language language)
{
    await languageRepository.CreateAsync(language, new PartitionKey(language.Name).ToString());
    return Ok();
}

Сам реп-метод:
public async Task CreateAsync(TEntity entity, string partitionKey)
{
    var itemResponse = await _container.CreateItemAsync<TEntity>(entity, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
    entity.Id = itemResponse.ActivityId;
}

При тестировании через постман:
{
    "Name": "English",
    "LanguageImage": ""
}

Получаю ошибку типу: PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header.
Проверил, что в контейнере у меня current paritition key:

Вопрос, что не так? Заранее спасибо
